# An operation was scaffolded that may result in the loss of data. Please review the migration for accuracy

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

One User has many Workouts.

One User has one History which is a List of Workouts.

The problem im getting is

> "There are multiple relationships between 'Workout' and 'User' without configured foreign key properties. This will cause Entity Framework to create shadow properties on 'Workout' with names dependent on the discovery order. Consider configuring the foreign key properties using the [ForeignKey] attribute or in 'OnModelCreating'.
> The foreign key property 'Workout.UserId1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'UserId' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type. See https://aka.ms/efcore-relationships for information on mapping relationships in EF Core.
> An operation was scaffolded that may result in the loss of data. Please review the migration for accuracy."

The project has [image: the project has these packages]

```
 public class Workout
 {
     [Key]
     public int WorkoutId { get; set; }

     public List<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
     public int CreatorId { get; set; }
     public string HistoryId { get; set; }

     public User Creator { get; set; }
     public Status Status { get; set; }

     public Workout()
     {
         Exercises = new List<Exercise>();
     }
     public Workout(User user)
     {
         Status = Status.Waiting;
         Creator = user;
         Exercises = new List<Exercise>();
     }

 }
```

```
  public class User
  {
      [Key]
      public int UserId { get; set; }


      [Required]
      public string Name { get; set; }

      [Required]
      public string Password { get; set; }

      public List<Workout> Workouts { get; set; }

      public List<Workout> History { get; set; }


      public User()
      {
          History = new List<Workout>();
          Workouts = new List<Workout>();
      }

      public User(string name , string password)
      {
          Password = password;
          Name = name;
          History = new List<Workout>();
          Workouts = new List<Workout>();

      }
  }
```

```
 public class MusclesDBContext : DbContext
 {
     public MusclesDBContext(): base()
     {

     }
     public MusclesDBContext(DbContextOptions contextOptions) : base(contextOptions)
     {

     }
     protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
     {
         optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=DESKTOP-PTKBD3O\\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=MusclesDB ;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;");
         base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
     }
     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.Entity<ExerciseType>().Property(a => a.TargetedMuscle).HasConversion<string>();
         modelBuilder.Entity<ExerciseType>().Property(o => o.Equipment).HasConversion<string>();
         modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(e => e.Workouts);
         modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(e => e.History);
         modelBuilder.Entity<Workout>().HasOne(e => e.Creator).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.CreatorId);
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     }

     public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Workout> Workouts { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
     public DbSet<ExerciseType> ExerciseTypes { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue will be that you have 3x one-to-many relationships between user and workouts:

- Workout.Creator
- User.Workouts
- User.History

You have only explicitly configured the first:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Workout>().HasOne(e => e.Creator).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.CreatorId);
```

... the other two are incomplete:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(e => e.Workouts);
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(e => e.History);
```

As there are no FKs declared for these relationships. The Workout *needs* a FK to a user to associate back to the user. You have one FK declared in the Creator ID but that has been mapped to a shadow "Many" side on the User.

You should look at your desired workflow for the system and the supporting data model. "Users" have workouts, and they have a history of workouts. But you also have a reference to a User on the workout for the Creator. Can a user create a workout for another different user? If they only create workouts for themselves, then the `.HasMany()` side of Creator could be User.Workouts:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Workout>().HasOne(e => e.Creator).WithMany(e => e.Workouts).HasForeignKey(c => c.CreatorId);
```

Continuing with the separate relationships to the same table, EF is warning you that the way you have the relationships declared if you want 3 disjointed relationships between User and Workout, it will end up doing something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Workout>().HasOne(e => e.Creator).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.CreatorId);
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(e => e.Workouts).WithOne().HasForeignKey("UserId_1");
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(e => e.History).WithOne().HasForeignKey("UserId_2");
```

Creating two more FKs to User within the Workout table. This really isn't recommended because it is technically possible to have different User FK values in the same Workout record when one would expect a workout to only ever belong to a single user.

When it comes to tracking historical data, I would recommend one of two approaches. Either move the data to a separate table/entity which can keep proper FKs without dual-purposing relationships between tables, or use something like an "IsArchived" or "IsActive" flag on the workout.

If you have a Workout table and a WorkoutHistory table, each table can have a CreatorId or UserId FK to associate back to the User table. The tables may have identical columns, or you can add/remove columns as needed from the WorkoutHistory to suit historical tracking. It really doesn't matter from a space perspective if you have 10,000 active workouts and 90,000 history records in two tables, or a mix of 100,000 active and historical records in a single table. What will matter is indexing performance if most of the time you are interested in just the active workouts.

Alternatively, having a single Workout table with an "IsArchived" flag means you just have a User.Workouts collection and query whether you are interested in active workouts or historical ones by filtering on `!IsArchived` if you just want the active ones.